# How do I use JavaScript to change the src of an <img> in a set cycle of multiple images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to have an image change through a set series as a button is clicked. How the JavaScript works is that it checks for which the current src matches and then changes it to whatever image is assigned to it. Where is the mistake?

```
function cycleImage() {

  var currentImage = document.getElementById("img-slide").src;
    if(currentImage == "/images/image-1.jpg") {
      document.getElementById("img-slide").src = "/images/image-2.jpg";
    }
    
    else if(currentImage == "/images/image-2.jpg") {
      document.getElementById("img-slide").src = "/images/image-3.jpg";
    }
    
    else if(currentImage == "/images/image-3.jpg") {
      document.getElementById("img-slide").src = "/images/image-4.jpg";
    }
    
    else if(currentImage == "/images/image-4.jpg") {
      document.getElementById("img-slide").src = "/images/image-1.jpg";
    }
}
```

Comment: It makes more sense to build the images into your markup and cycle through them using the `nextChildren()` method.

Comment: "Where is the mistake" — Why do you think there is a mistake? You've said what you want and provided some code that looks, on first glance, like it should work. Does the behaviour not match what you expect? How so? Are any errors logged to the Console?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Stackoverflow supports live demos where you can include both your JS and the relevant HTML. You can use services like http://placekitten.com/ to have image URLs which people who don't have access to your computer can test with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at `currentSource`, you'll see that it's a fully-resolved URL (like `https://example.com/images/image-1.jpg`, not a relative URL (like `/images/image-1.jpg`), so it won't match any of the strings you're comparing it with. That's because the [`src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/src) property provides a full-resolved URL, not the literal value of the `src` attribute.

While you *could* use [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) to do the comparison instead (or use [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to get the actual attribute value), I wouldn't do it that way. Instead, I'd keep track in a variable:

```
let imageIndex = 1;
setImage();
function setImage() {
    document.getElementById("img-slide").src = `/images/image-${imageIndex}.jpg`;
}
function cycleImage() {
    imageIndex = (imageIndex % 4) + 1;
    setImage();
}
```

Live Example (using `div` elements instead of images):

```js
let imageIndex = 1;
setImage();
function setImage() {
    document.getElementById("img-slide").textContent = `/images/image-${imageIndex}.jpg`;
}
function cycleImage() {
    imageIndex = (imageIndex % 4) + 1;
    setImage();
}
setInterval(cycleImage, 800);
```

```html
<div id="img-slide"></div>
```

That `imageIndex = (imageIndex % 4) + 1;` thing is a useful trick: it increments a 1-based number, wrapping back around to 1 after it's had a given maximum value (in this case, 4). So we get `1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4...`. (You don't strictly need the `()` in it, but it's useful for understanding how it works.)

Or if the image paths weren't easily generated like that, I'd use an array of images paths and loop through it:

```
const images = [
    "/something.jpg",
    "/something-else.png",
    "/a-different-thing.jpg",
    "/yet-another-thing.jpg",
    // ...
];
let imageIndex = 0;
setImage();
function setImage() {
    document.getElementById("img-slide").src = images[imageIndex];
}
function cycleImage() {
    imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1) % images.length;
    setImage();
}
```

Live Example (using `div` elements instead of images):

```js
const images = [
    "/something.jpg",
    "/something-else.png",
    "/a-different-thing.jpg",
    "/yet-another-thing.jpg",
    // ...
];
let imageIndex = 0;
setImage();
function setImage() {
    document.getElementById("img-slide").textContent = images[imageIndex];
}
function cycleImage() {
    imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1) % images.length;
    setImage();
}
setInterval(cycleImage, 800);
```

```html
<div id="img-slide"></div>
```

That `imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1) % images.length` is another useful trick similar to the one above. It increments a **0-based** value, wrapping it around back to `0` when (before) it reaches a maximum value (in this case, `images.length`, which is `4`). So we get `0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3...`. (You **do** need the ()`in this one, because`%`has a higher precedence than`+`.)

Comment: Thank you so much, i much prefer this method than the one I was trying to fit. Thanks. I'll upvote when I have enough reputation